# Uniform Rectifiability

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request, harmonic-analysis, geometric-measure-theory

What is the definition of uniform rectifiability as used in the context of analytic capacity of compact sets in $\mathbb{C}$?

The precise context is [this paper](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2118585?uid=3737864&uid=2129&uid=2&uid=70&uid=4&sid=21102500141667) by Mattila, Mernikov and Verdera.

Comment: Where have you seen the term used?

Comment: In this article http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2118585?uid=3737864&uid=2129&uid=2&uid=70&uid=4&sid=21102500141667 by Mattila, Mernikov and Verdera. They refer to David/Semmes but I have no access to the cited source.

Answer (score 1):

A closed set $E\subset\mathbb{C}$ is called *uniformly rectifiable* if there exists a curve $E\subset\Gamma\subset\mathbb{C}$ and $C>0$ such that
$$\mathcal{H}^1(\Gamma\cap B(z,r))\le Cr$$
for $z\in\Gamma$ and $r>0$ where $\mathcal{H}^1$ denotes 1-dimensional Hausdorff measure and $B(z,r)=\{w\in\mathbb{C}\,:\,|z-w|\le r\}$.